# GET http://localhost:3000/[object%20File] 404 (Not Found) Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on Angular-NestJs project. When I click on a product for update, the update form get's populated with all the info of the product and with image also, I'm using **setter** and **getter** for populating form. And in my update form I'm displaying the product's current image at the top, and at the botttom of the form I have an **input of file type** to choose new image If someone want to update the image. So when I select a new image at the bottom of the form, the first current image that is at the top of the form, just disappear and shows image break logo. And in console I get the error

> GET http://localhost:3000/[object%20File] 404 (Not Found)

**Before selecting new Image**

[image]

**After Selecting New Image**

[image]

**Image of the error**

[image]

**And when I click at the line pointed by blue arrow in the above image, it take me to the following piece of code and points at `src` line ,where I'm am displaying my current image of the product**

```
<span
  class="text-center text-[1.25rem] text-green-600 font-bold mb-[-2rem]"
>
  Current Image
</span>
<img
  src="http://localhost:3000/{{
    bookForm.value.image.toString().replace('./assets', '')
  }}"
  alt=""
  class="p-[0.5rem] h-[300px] w-[300px]"
/>
```

**Form to load previous content of the product**

```
  bookForm!: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(): void {

    const bookData = this.service.bookGetter();
    this.bookForm = new FormGroup({
      _id: new FormControl(bookData?._id),
      name: new FormControl(bookData?.name, [Validators.required]),
      author: new FormControl(bookData?.author, [Validators.required]),
      price: new FormControl(bookData?.price, [Validators.required]),
      image: new FormControl(bookData?.image, [Validators.required]),
    });
    
    console.log('After', this.bookForm.value);

  }
```

**Function to select new images in ts**

```
imagedata?: string;

async attachFile(event: any) {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files![0];
    this.bookForm.patchValue({ image: file });
    const allowedMimeTypes = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg'];
    this.bookForm.get('image')?.updateValueAndValidity();
    if (file && allowedMimeTypes.includes(file.type)) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        this.imagedata = reader.result as string;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      console.log(file);
    }
  }
```

**html where function is called**

```
<div class="imagediv flex flex-col items-start">
          <span class="text-center text-[1.25rem] text-green-600 font-bold">
            Choose New Image
          </span>
          <input class="" type="file" (change)="attachFile($event)" />
          <br />
          <img
            *ngIf="imagedata"
            [src]="imagedata"
            alt=""
            class="p-[0.5rem] h-[200px] w-[200px]"
          />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing old image and new, i.e. uploaded image from the server is being replaced by new image File object, and there is no new image yet, so localhost part will never display image like that.

Solution might be to split it, and add a new form control for a new image:

```
newImage: new FormControl('')

this.bookForm.patchValue({ newImage: file });
```

Comment: With your solution the image broke at the first hand. When I click on edit button the image does not display on update form , instead it shows broke image logo, like it use to show when I choose new image, in second image  I uploaded in my question. And with your solution I even doesn't need to choose new image, it's already broke, whether I choose new image or not

Comment: @MNouman try the updated code. if it doesn't work, can you include html form controls as well, it looks like you're mixing old image and new right now, i.e. string on the server is replaced by new image object... so maybe you'd need to introduce new form control, for example "newImage"..

Comment: The current solution is also not working,although I don't see any error in cosole,but the image is broke,when I check `Network` , there is an image with status `200` and type of `text/html` . I've already provided my formcontrols  and the new `imagedata` variable in my question. Please see my question again.  Also one thing I want tell is that the updating functionality is working fine. If I does not select image the old image still remians, and If I select new image, then the product is updated with new image. So the current issue is not effecting any functionality at all.

Comment: @MNouman you are using `image` control for both old and new image, when you update it, the old string that loads image from the server fails, because it gets object, and there is no string anyway.. so that cannot work. yes, it will get saved, but not displayed. I think you should split those two, try now

Comment: This solution and logic worked. Lots of thanks for your time and efforts...